# How to get a page cached by the browser

Tags: browser-cache

I am trying to get a page cached by the user's browser, but I can't quite figure out how do it.  How can I get a page cached, and how much of the page are going to be cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an automatic process on the browser, unless you have specifically disabled caching on your webserver and/or code.